Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с постановкой запятых в сложном предложении
Уже курились зелёным дымком верхушки госпитальных тополей, и когда Саенко, уходя, открывал для нас окно, которое в общем-то открывать не разрешалось, мы пьянели от пряной тополевой горечи порвавшегося воздуха.
Почему после союза "и" нет запятой, ведь нет второй части союза "когда"?

Sharon, а почему Вы откатили правку? Я ведь, кажется, сделала всё правильное и нужное: отметила цитату, авторский текст не  меняла, выделила союз "и", поправила сложный союз, добавила необходимые метки... Чего ж такое неприятие?

Спорный вопрос с разными решениями, поэтому мне хотелось оставить авторский вариант, в том числе метки. Вообще говоря, править вопросы без явных ошибок не стоит, иначе можно упустить то, в чем именно были у автора сомнения.

Я ничего не упустила. А явные ошибки, конечно же, есть...  Но — как скажете.

Корректно:
Уже курились зелёным дымком верхушки госпитальных тополей, и, когда Саенко, уходя, открывал для нас окно, которое в общем-то открывать не разрешалось, мы пьянели от пряной тополевой горечи порвавшегося воздуха.
Запятая после союза "и" нужна! Придаточное можно извлечь или переставить в конец предложения:
Уже курились зелёным дымком верхушки госпитальных тополей, и мы пьянели от пряной тополевой горечи порвавшегося воздуха, когда Саенко, уходя, открывал для нас окно, которое в общем-то открывать не разрешалось.
У Розенталя масса примеров: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140

Действительно, все верно. Если перестановка возможна, то запятая нужна.

@Серж А вы о каких правилах говорите?  Разве у Розенталя или в ПАС есть примеры, где в составе придаточного есть две предикативные основы? А по Лопатину сложные предложения с тремя предикативными основами должны решаться методом блоков. Или это не так и у меня неправильное решение по блокам?

В сложных синтаксических конструкциях, т. е. в сложных предложениях с разнотипной синтаксической связью (с сочинением и подчинением; с сочинением и бессоюзной связью; с подчинением и бессоюзной связью; с сочинением, подчинением и бессоюзной связью), знаки препинания ставятся на общих основаниях (см. § 112, 115, 119, 127) — учитывается вид союзов, смысловые взаимоотношения частей предложения, порядок их расположения.

В сложных синтаксических конструкциях, распадающихся на крупные логико-синтаксические блоки, которые сами по себе являются сложными предложениями или в которых один из блоков оказывается сложным предложением, на стыке блоков ставятся знаки препинания, указывающие на взаимоотношения блоков, при сохранении внутренних знаков, поставленных на своем собственном синтаксическом основании.

В параграфе речь идет о знаках на стыке блоков. При этом надо учитывать внутренних знаки, поставленных на собственных основаниях. У нас речь не об этом.

@Серж А зачем запятую в начале второго блока поставили? Какое уж тут соединение двух блоков союзом И? Или вы этого не видите? Предложение делится запятыми  на три части, в том числе интонационно, так что нет у вас никаких блоков.  Схоластика одна. А если еще добавить предикации в придаточное, тоже ничего не изменится и переставлять будете? // И дополнительные вопросы::  (1) приведите подобные примеры из классической литературы (три предик. основы); (2) обоснуйте правку авторского текста.

С чего вы вообще взяли, что спорная запятая - это внутренний знак, если вы ставите его в начале блока? С другой стороны,  ваши перестановочки  в правилах Розенталя должны касаться отдельных  предикативных частей, а вы сразу две переставляете. Или и так сойдет? Неужели такой примитивный формализм лежит в основе гибкой системы русской пунктуации по Розенталю?

Рассмотрим: Уже курились зелёным дымком верхушки госпитальных тополей(,) и мы пьянели от пряной тополевой горечи порвавшегося воздуха, когда Саенко, уходя, открывал для нас окно, которое в общем-то открывать не разрешалось. //  4 предикативные основы, как разделить на 2 блока?  Наверное, по союзу КОГДА. Но тогда два первых предложения в первом блоке будет объединять  второй блок, и они должны произноситься без паузы. Тогда убирайте запятую в первой части. // Вот такие у ВАС синтаксические игры с предикативными основами.

Про интонацию я уж и не говорю, это terra incognita для тех, кто не пользуется интонационным анализом. Вы не понимаете, какие внутренние интонационные перестройки делаются в таком сложном предложении при добавлении лишней предикативной основы. Но все это нужно учитывать при прочтении теста, надо голосом обозначить цельность второго блока, а вы своей запятой дезориентируете читателя. Это понимают писатели на уровне интуиции, но не вы.

Я вообще считаю, что авторские тесты признанных писателей нужно занести в КРАСНУЮ КНИГУ. Это и наша история, и современное состояние языка, можно сказать, ценность русской культуры. Насколько я знаю, тексты классиков 19 века стараются не править в соответствии с современным правилам. Так, раньше были другие требование в грамматике в отношении галлицизмов в теме деепричастных оборотов, но авторская пунктуация сохраняется.  Тексты таких писателей защищают нас от варварства и небрежности, присущей современной литературе. И не секрет такое мнение: как же вы ДОСТАЛИ со своей грамотностью.

Правильно без запятой, как было в авторском тексте:
Уже курились зелёным дымком верхушки госпитальных тополей, и когда Саенко, уходя, открывал для нас окно, которое в общем-то открывать не разрешалось, мы пьянели от пряной тополевой горечи порвавшегося воздуха.
Пояснение

Вопрос был о том, почему запятой нет у автора. "Красное вино победы" — рассказ Евгения Носова, который живо передаёт атмосферу "праздника со слезами на глазах".

Так почему же? Необходимо править авторский текст или все же можно объяснить отсутствие запятой? Это сложное предложение с сочинительной (союз И) и подчинительной связью (союз КОГДА, с.с. КОТОРОЕ). Попробуем решить по Лопатину методом блоков: § 132.

Здесь два блока, основной будет сочинительная связь, союз И.  Второй блок выглядит так: Когда Саенко, уходя, открывал для нас окно, которое в общем-то открывать не разрешалось, мы пьянели от пряной тополевой горечи порвавшегося воздуха. Это СПП с двумя придаточными, и оно воспринимается как единое целое, в том числе читается как цельная конструкция

Постановка запятой перед вторым блоком после союза И будет некорректной, так как союз И относится ко всему блоку.

Вывод. Главное при решении подобных задач —  проверить структурную схему конкретного предложения (об этом говорит Розенталь), в то время как возможность перестановки — это только способ проверки.



Интересно, что в некоторых изданиях запятая имеется. (https://www.rulit.me/books/krasnoe-vino-pobedy-shopen-sonata-nomer-dva-rasskaz-povest-read-625524-6.html)

Интересно? Возможно, это правка авторского текста по формальному признаку, который был предложен. Поэтому надо разбираться с рукописями и первым изданием. Но судя по готовности, с которой утверждается ошибочное написание у автора без запятой, похоже на поздние правки. Потому что понять отсутствие запятой куда как сложнее, чем ее присутствие..

Правильно:
Уже курились зелёным дымком верхушки госпитальных тополей, и когда Саенко, уходя, открывал для нас окно, которое в общем-то открывать не разрешалось, мы пьянели от пряной тополевой горечи порвавшегося воздуха.
Пояснение

В общем случае классические правила Розенталя § 36 пункт 4 и ПАС § 123 связывают постановку или отсутствие запятой на стыке союзов И КОГДА с возможностью структурной перестройки предложения при изъятии придаточного. Наличие двойного союза КОГДА...ТО — это лишь формальное условие для отсутствия запятой, но возможны и другие варианты.

В данном случае изъятие придаточной части невозможно из-за наличия внутри временного придаточного (союз КОГДА) определительного придаточного (союзное слово КОТОРОЕ).



Лирическое отступление по теме: Надо ли нам править писателей?
ВСТУПЛЕНИЕ

Стоит сказать, что стать "грамотнее" писателей не так сложно: надо выучить правила Розенталя и ПАС (или хотя бы ориентироваться в них), а также научиться искать примеры по теме. И вот уже можно дать уверенный ответ: надо поставить запятую в авторском тексте, которую он непонятно почему пропустил. Да и корректоры-редакторы оказались не на высоте — тоже, видно, не особо разбирались в письменной грамотности.

Я здесь за адвоката писателя, потому что форум фактически поддержал правку. Защищаю я его с помощью метода блоков Лопатина, но метод выглядит  как совершенная экзотика. Ведь однозначно ясно: нет двойного союза КОГДА...ТО, а у Розенталя "масса примеров" по теме. Но я уже который раз предлагаю вспомнить того же Розенталя:
Особенности русской пунктуации — в присущей ей 
многофункциональности знаков препинания и широкой их 
взаимозаменяемости, в своеобразии индивидуально- 
авторского использования знаков препинания, в гибкости 
пунктуационной системы, позволяющей выявлять не только 
смысловую сторону текста, но и стилистические его 
оттенки. Все это исключает формальный подход к соблюдению 
правил.


Розенталь предлагает базовые решения задач по пунктуации, как учитель математика предлагает школьникам решение типовых задач. Но решать-то конкретные примеры нужно самим, а не копировать решения у Розенталя. Ведь не секрет, что любая нестандартная задача вызывает неизбежные трудности у пользователей.


РЕШЕНИЕ

Смотрим внимательно грамматику по теме. Наличие двойных союзов — вот что определяет однозначность решения. Но это ясно видно на примере союза ЧЕМ...ТЕМ: Звуки постепенно замирали, и чем дальше уходили мы от дома, тем глуше и мертвее становилось вокруг (М. Г.)

А вот с двойным союзом КОГДА...ТО надо еще разобраться — дело в том, что вторая часть союза ТО не является обязательной. Местоимение ТО обычно используется в сложных конструкциях, чтобы обозначить границу между придаточной и главной частью. Но в приведенном предложении, где много запятых, как раз можно использовать ТО. Но писатель принимает другое решение — просто не ставит запятую после союза И, надеясь на наше понимание цельности второй части предложения.


ВЫВОД
А мне бы хотелось, чтобы пользователи русского языка поняли следующее: по большому счету не писатели пишут по правилам, а правила были составлены по произведениям писателей. Безусловно, коррекция правил по современным практическим текстам нужна, но этим должны заниматься профессиональные лингвисты.
И метод блоков Лопатина для сложных предложений (от трех предикативных основ) тоже никто не отменял.
